# User input from scanner method to array of 5 indexes also gives user ability to delete any index

Tags: java, arrays, string

User input from scanner method to array of 5 indexes also gives user ability to delete any index matching with string from one of the index.
ALL I want to achieve in this is in this while loop I would like to settle city (option 1), which means creating one as you can probably see from my code. This is where user will type any name they like no restrictions. once they settle the city loops starts again. However it does remember that user created a city earlier. I can have upto 5 cities. There is cost associate with settling new city. I know how to do those conditionals. I am just not sure about this string array.

**ArrayList or Array class is not allowed.**

where as, option 2 I can demolish any of the city i have created by giving user lists of city they have made earlier. I have to keep minimum of at least one city.

**IF you are wondering then this is based on Civilization game.**

Please ask for clarification as this may not be
 straight forward. thanks

```
while (playing) {
            System.out.println("\nPlease make your selection!");
            System.out.println("\n1. Settle a City"
                + "\n2. Demolish a City"
                + "\n3. Build Militia"
                + "\n4. Research Technology"
                + "\n5. Attack Enemy City"
                + "\n6. End Turn\n");

            String gameChoice = userinput.nextLine();

            if (gameChoice.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to"
                    + " name your city?");

                String cityname = userinput.nextLine();
                cityname = cityNames[0];




            } else if (gameChoice.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("What city would you like to demolish?");

                for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
                    System.out.print(cityNames[i]);
                    System.out.print("");
                }




            } else if (gameChoice.equals("3")) {
                System.out.println("You have military points");

            } else if (gameChoice.equals("4")) {
                System.out.println("You have Research Technology points");

            } else if (gameChoice.equals("5")) {
                System.out.println("You have zero points");

            } else {
                System.out.println(" Thanks for playing ");

            }




            playing = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, here:

```java
String cityname = userinput.nextLine();
cityname = cityNames[0];
```

You are assigning cityname to user input and then you are assigning it to something in cityNames array, that doesn't make sense, maybe you pasted wrong or something, but just in case, this should be the other way around, like this:

```
cityNames[0] = cityname;
```

You have `playing = false` at the end so the loop is gonna just end when user types the city name, you need to either remove this `playing = false` or use `continue;` after `cityNames[0] = cityName;`, that's gonna go to the next iteration of a loop, without going all the way down to `playing = false`.